# Align different time series to same start

Tags: r, time-series

I am having multiple time series with the same frequencies but different starting times and different lengths. I want to align them at the same start to better compare them.

Data:

```
series1, 2016-01-01, 10,
series1, 2016-01-02, 9,
series1, 2016-01-03, 11,
...
series2, 2016-03-05, 14,
series2, 2016-03-06, 15, 
series2, 2016-03-08, 16,
```

Should be output to something like this:

```
0000, series1, 10,
0000, series2, 14,
0000, seriesX, X,
0001, series1, 9,
0001, series2, 15,
0001, seriesX, X,
0002, series1, 11,
0002, series2, NA,
0002, seriesX, X,
```

output of head:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id                       ts
     <dbl>                    <list>
1       1   <data.frame [5,265 x 3]>
2       2   <data.frame [2,771 x 3]>
3       3     <data.frame [825 x 3]>
4       4   <data.frame [2,640 x 3]>
5       5   <data.frame [2,838 x 3]>
6       6   <data.frame [426 x 3]>
```

head of one of the ts xts object:

```
                            id                   value
2010-04-10 23:53:00          1                   14.60
2010-04-10 23:58:00          2                   15.83
2010-04-11 00:03:00          3                   13.76
2010-04-11 00:08:00          4                   12.96
```

The data is currently in a tibble with xts, but I did not find a way to align them by time, only merge same timestamps. Using an index instead of timecounter does not work as there may be missing timestamps.

How can I align the timeseries to a single series starting at 0?

Comment: Can you use `dput(head(DF,10)` to post a small subset of your dataset.

Comment: For the comparisons you want to make, do you need the re-indexed series to be time-series objects, or would a data frame or some other tabular form be sufficient?

Comment: A timeseries would be optimal, but a data frame would be sufficient for the moment.